# Drawable resources don`t match with physical devices

Tags: android, screen-resolution, android-drawable

I have 2 testing device and same images in different size and folders.

Samsug Galaxy S2 retrieves from `hdpi` which has image **(300x300)**

Google Nexus 7 is retrieves from `xhdpi` which has image **(400x400)**

When i run the application on both devices, even tough i confirmed they read from different resources, same size image appears, so that, when image fits the screen size in S2, it looks very small for Nexus 7.

Should i go for some other configurations? I have no idea how i can fix this. Thank you for suggestions.

**`.xml`** for the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/stainbck"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp"
android:id="@+id/rootViewGroup" >

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/newcard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="@color/trans"
    android:src="@drawable/contactnew" />  **//THIS IS SOURCE DRAWABLE**

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** Eclipse have hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi resources.

Comment: add this image into `Drawable` folder

Comment: You want to scale the imagebutton or not? Check out scaleType: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html in order to get the layout you want?

Comment: i have no Drawable folder. should i create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html):

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

for `ImageButton` that it can fit for different screen sizes.

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/newcard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
android:background="@color/trans"
android:src="@drawable/contactnew"
android:scaleType="fitXY" />        **//Scale Type**
```

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 7 supports an XHDPI images
Samsung s2 supports an HPDI images

You need to create two folder for two different screen resolution their name must be like

drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi

put your 300*300 image into drawable-hdpi and 400*400 image into drawable-xhdpi
and keep one thing in mind that both image must have same name with same extention

hope it will help you to get your solution

Comment: thank you but this is exactly what i have done actually. i think my problem is with scaleType in .xml file. im working on this.